# Conditionally apply IE8 specific styles inside css file without if else conditional

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a CSS file which will be used by all browsers, now I would like to add an IE8 specific CSS declaration, in the same stylesheet, which is conditionally applied if the user is browsing using IE8. I don't want to add any IE8 specific HTML markup. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

\9 is a hack for IE 8 and lower version

for eg.

```
.class {
  color: red; /* this property will work for all browser */
  color: red\9; /* this property will work on IE8 and lower version of IE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

     `<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
     <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
     <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
     <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
     <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->`

CSS

    `.ie7 {
      ...
    }
    .ie8 {
      ...
    }`

HTML paste the comments on your top of page in HTML file access css styles with .ie7 or .ie9 classes. This is Paul-Irish's way of targetting IE Browsers.

Thanks
~Sahib